# How can I check the type of my generic variable?

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to check whether the generic variable `T` is a type of `User` or `Post`, which both conform to protocol `LiveObject`

```
class LiveManager<T:LiveObject> {
    var resources = Dictionary<Int, T>()
    init(){
    }
    func something(){
        //How can I check whether T is a User or a Post?
    }
}
```

This is my full class:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

protocol LiveObject {
    init(data:JSON)
    func startListeningToFirebase(clientName: String) -> Void
    func stopListeningToFirebase(clientName: String) -> Void
}

class LiveManager<T:LiveObject> {
    let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    let queue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()

    var resources = Dictionary<Int, T>()
    var clients = Dictionary<Int, Set<String>>()

    init(){

    }

    private func addToClientMap(id: Int, clientName: String){
        if clients[id] == nil {
            clients[id] = Set<String>()
            clients[id]!.insert(clientName)
        }else{
            clients[id]!.insert(clientName)
        }
    }

    func getResource(id: Int, clientName: String) -> T?{
        if let resource = resources[id] {
            addToClientMap(id, clientName: clientName)
            return resource
        }else{
            return nil
        }
    }

    func createResource(data:JSON, clientName: String, listenToFirebase: Bool) -> T? {
        if let id = data["id"].int {
            if let resource = resources[id] {
                addToClientMap(id, clientName: clientName)
                if listenToFirebase { resource.startListeningToFirebase(clientName) }
                return resource
            }else{
                resources[id] = T(data: data)
                addToClientMap(id, clientName: clientName)
                if listenToFirebase { resources[id]!.startListeningToFirebase(clientName) }
                return resources[id]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func createResource(id: Int, clientName: String, listenToFirebase: Bool, completion:(resource: T?) -> Void)  {

    }


    func releaseResource(id: Int, clientName: String){
        print(clientName + " -- release resource")
        print(clients)
        if clients[id] != nil {
            clients[id]!.remove(clientName)
            if clients[id]!.count == 0 {
                print("Client count is zero - remove this from resources")
                resources.removeValueForKey(id)
                clients.removeValueForKey(id)
            }
        }
    }

    func startListeningToFirebase(id: Int, clientName: String) -> Bool{
        if let resource = resources[id] {
            resource.startListeningToFirebase(clientName)
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }
    }

    func stopListeningToFirebase(id: Int, clientName: String) -> Bool{
        if let resource = resources[id] {
            resource.stopListeningToFirebase(clientName)
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @matt it's not unclear. It's a class that accepts generic variables.  Inside init, I'd like to check what type "T" is.  Can someone explain why this is downvoted?

Comment: Yes, it compiles. I'll paste my class.

Comment: @matt can you explain to me what's so hard to understand about my question? I think it's pretty clear what I'm asking.

Comment: Well, for one thing, you wrote: "User or Post, which are both subclasses of LiveObject". That made no sense, given your code. But now that you've posted your _real_ code, it turns out that User and Post are _not_ subclasses of LiveObject; they conform to the _protocol_ LiveObject. That makes sense — but it isn't what you said. So you see, you were very careless in the way you originally phrased your question, but that was the only information you gave.

Comment: @matt - you're right - sorry!

Comment: So, now that you've provided more information: You've got a generic class. But how is the generic actually resolved? You have an empty `init`, so how do you actually create an instance of this generic class? — To put it another way: Your question, in your comment in `init`, is: "How can I check whether T is a User or a Post?" But in your `init`, _there is no T_, so your question makes no sense. Again I ask you, as I asked you earlier: if you know that this thing is a LiveObject, what sense does it make for your class to be a generic?

Comment: As pointed out in DrBeardface's answer, the real question is why would you want to do that?  It defeats the whole point of generics and subclassing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say something like this:

```
init() {
    if T.self == User.self {
        print("T is User")
    }
    else if T.self == Post.self {
        print("T is Post")
    }
}
```

However, while you can do this, I feel like this kind of defeats the purpose of using generics.

Comment: Depending on the type, I need to call a different method.  I don't need to check the type during init(). How can I modify my protocol so that it includes different methods for each type?

Comment: I don't see what's stopping you from replacing the `print(...)` calls I made with whatever methods you want.

Comment: "Depending on the type, I need to call a different method. I don't need to check the type during init(). How can I modify my protocol so that it includes different methods for each type" Sorry to keep on about this, but it goes to the heart of what I keep saying. Saying "if x is such-and-such a class" is a Bad Smell. Use OOP! If you need User and Post to do different things, those things should belong to User and Post separately, not to some generic class. There should be no such generic. If User and Post have things in common, give them a common superclass and put them there!

Answer (score -1):

check isKindOfClass and other related checkers depending on what specifically you want to check.